# On desktop PC, mobile css loads first, then it switches to the desktop version

Tags: css, responsive-design

So I have a website, with the responsive css (Mobile oriented). CSS stylesheet has rules for the mobile version, then (in the end of the file) @media queries start for the screens wider, then mobile.

When a page is loaded on desktop (and if this page is not cached by the browser), mobile css loades first, then in less then a second, it switches to the desktop styles. So it blinks with mobile version css (considering the fact, that desktop is wider then mobile screen, it stretches huge elements through out the page), then looks fine.

I understand, that the browser needs to load the stylesheet completely, and before it did so, it shows what it has already loaded. I understand, that this behavior is explainable, but it still bugs me.

Is there a way to load the css without blinking with mobile version (but WITHOUT making it desktop oriented (so that the desktop css loaded first, and the rest was handled by the @media queries)) and should I even bother about it (or is it just fine and should remain that way)?

**Here is some code:**

Meta tags before CSS:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/icn.png" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/icn.png" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Invoking CSS from an HTML file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/page1.css">
```

CSS File example (shortened (this is just an example of the structure of CSS in the file)):

```
html {
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
}
body {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-size:16px;
}
.first-panel {
    background: black;
    width:250px;
    height:100vh;
    color:white;
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    clear:both;
    top:0
}
.no-user-select {
    -webkit-user-select:none;
    -moz-user-select:none;
    -ms-user-select:none;
    user-select:none
}
@media only screen and (min-width:480px) {
}
@media only screen and (min-width:640px) {
}
@media only screen and (min-width:768px) {  
}
@media only screen and (min-width:1024px) {
    .first-panel {
        background: white;
        color:black;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width:1280px) {
}
```

Comment: Show us how you load your CSS.

Comment: Move everything to single CSS file and load it in `<head>`.

Comment: @Daut CSS files? With html stylesheet tags. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/page1.css">`

Comment: @Justinas all of the rules are in a single file and are loaded in `<head>`

Comment: @Mee Based on what you say - that is not really possible. There is something that we cannot just guess. 
Share some code/

Comment: @Daut I have added code to the question

Comment: Have you set the viewport properly

Comment: @Daut as you see, in the meta tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few approach you can use

1st Approach by using CSS File

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 600px)" href="small.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 4000px)" href="big.css">
```

2nd by using Javascript

```
if (window.matchMedia('screen and (min-width: 600px)')){
  document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" 
                  href="small.css">');
}
```

I suggest for better one you need use only one css file and define the concept like as below :

```
@media (min-width:320px)  { /* smartphones, portrait iPhone, portrait 480x320 phones (Android) */ }
@media (min-width:480px)  { /* smartphones, Android phones, landscape iPhone */ }
@media (min-width:600px)  { /* portrait tablets, portrait iPad, e-readers (Nook/Kindle), landscape 800x480 phones (Android) */ }
@media (min-width:801px)  { /* tablet, landscape iPad, lo-res laptops ands desktops */ }
@media (min-width:1025px) { /* big landscape tablets, laptops, and desktops */ }
@media (min-width:1281px) { /* hi-res laptops and desktops */ }
```

Comment: I have posted some code, that I have used. Wouldnt the first approach give the same result as I have? Also what is the difference between how I have handled the queries and your suggestion. P. S. I think JS will load CSS even slower. Also, what do you think about the code, that I have just posted. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: better you can use min and max both like this @media only screen and (min-width:640px) and (max-width:767px) {} which will target the same screen size

Comment: That has been suggested by J. Sadi. I have tried it, and it forces to add `!important` after each style inside the query-selector. Adding this word is usually a bad approach + I have a LOT of rules in CSS, so using this word all the time is not a good option.

Comment: Ok, so I have decided, that the best approach for optimizing this css would be to divide this big stylesheet into smaller ones and request them with media queries in html (approach 1, as described by SantoshK). This would require coping all of the global rules through out those small files, but with changes from the queries.

Comment: I only not sure, will the browser load so much data or just the file it needs for this kind of screen.  If it will load all of the data, then I'll have to set up some system to determine the width of the screen with php (by header information or JS Ajax or smth) and then php should decide, which css file to send

Comment: with this rules above the browser will load both css files if width is over 4000px

Comment: @J.Sadi yes it will include the both file for more info you can visit : https://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/   if you wanted to use optimize with only one css than go with media minwidth devicesize

Answer (score 1):

Adding "max-width" to your media-selector should do the trick:

```
@media only screen and (min-width:480px) and (max-width: 639px) {
}
@media only screen and (min-width:640px) and (max-width: 767px) {
}
@media only screen and (min-width:768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {  
}
@media only screen and (min-width:1024px) and (max-width: 1279px) {
    .first-panel {
        background: white;
        color:black;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width:1280px) {
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. If it helps, will mark as correct

Comment: Note that if you're setting styles of a class outside of a media-selector, too. you maybe have to override it inside the media-selector using `!important;`

Comment: I have tried this, and it does not work without adding `!important` inside a media-selector (as you have specified in your comment). I have way too much styles to use `!important` all the time. Also using this word is a bad approach and should be avoided if possible. It is only for "emergency",  so to say, situations.

Comment: in this case you've set your styles the wrong way. Then you should not set the styles outside the media-selectors. These are the two options you have: you could set styles "globally" and override it inside media-selectors, OR you could set these styles using the media-selector only.

Comment: well, in this case, the styles will not be preserved. What I mean is: the .first-panel has a set of rules to it, while one of the media queries overwrites only two of them (background and color). If the those styles wont load (if I put the global rules into a media tag), then the page would be displayed incorrectly

Comment: if you want to override global rules you have to use `!important;` to override it. The only alternative is setting this styles to each media-selector. To my knowlege, unfortunately there is no other way… maybe you could try setting the media-selecors first.

Comment: I have actually tried setting media selectors first, and then loading the global rules. But in this case global rules overwrite the media selectors.

Comment: I was also thinking, if I could make global rules - only the rules, that are NOT overwritten, and in media selectors to write the rules, that ARE overwritten. In this case I would need a media selector for the phone width as well. But in this case, the rules, that are initially defined in the phone view and then overwritten in the desktop view, should be copied to the phone horizontal, tablet and tablet horizontal views. And the desktop view should be copied to the wide-desktop view.... So it would require a lot of duplicated information

Comment: yep, but thats the way it goes within css. already thinked about scss?

Comment: You mean Sass? I prefer Stylus.